# printing streaming result every 5min interval in python

Tags: python, pandas

The strategy1 method will be called for every record that comes every 1sec. I am trying to print the 5min mean value of column "ltt" every 5min. But with below code, the print is seen every 1sec. Can someone please suggest on how to do this.
The streaming input i.e record has to captured every 1sec, only the print has to be done every 5min.

```
import pandas as pd

def strategy1(record):
    global datalist

    datalist.append(record)
    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(datalist)
    pandas_df['ltt'] = pd.to_datetime(pandas_df['ltt'], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

    pandas_df['hour'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.hour
    pandas_df['minute'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.minute
    pandas_df['second'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.second
    print(pandas_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='ltt', axis=0, freq='5min')).mean())
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: @Timus I think the problem is that he is using only timstamps in the data. If there is longer than 5 min gap, it doesn't work. He needs to bin the data in set intervals and count mean in  the bins.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague. I interpret this to mean: 'I want to calculate mean every 5 minutes.'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#some sample data... 
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['11.11.2020 12:00:00', '11.11.2020 12:01:00', '11.11.2020 12:02:00', '11.11.2020 12:11:00', '11.11.2020 12:13:00'], 'val':[1, 2, 3, 11, 12]})
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
```

Lets create bins, which catch everything every 5 minutes. (13 and not 12 , because we begin with 0.)

```
my_bins = np.linspace(0,60,13)
data['bin'] = pd.cut(data['time'].dt.minute, bins = my_bins )
data['hour'] = data['time'].dt.hour
```

Remember to groupby both bin and hour (and date if needed) because every hour has the same minute values.

```
data.groupby(['hour','bin'])['val'].mean()
```

`hour  bin
12    (0.0, 5.0]       2.5
      (5.0, 10.0]      NaN
      (10.0, 15.0]    11.5
      (15.0, 20.0]     NaN
      (20.0, 25.0]     NaN
      ....`

Comment: Hm, I don't really understand why you're using bins, `pd.cut` and the `hour` column? Doesn't `data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5min'))['val'].mean()` essentially produce the same output?

Comment: @Timus Yes it does. There are may ways, no arguments from me.

Comment: Yes! I was only asking because that is OPs method and I still don't understand what's wrong with it.